# Is it a legal operation to invert both sides of a linear algebra equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying Stang's linear algebra book. One of the questions is:

$$AB = C, \text{ find a formula for } A^{-1}$$

I solved this as:

$$(AB)^{-1} = C^{-1}$$
$$B^{-1}A^{-1} = C^{-1}$$
$$A^{-1} = BC^{-1}$$

This is correct according to answer at the back of the book, however I couldn't find a reference to say taking the inverse of both sides is allowable, or if instead I had to do it with some method of multiplication.

Comment: The problem seems incomplete or not fully stated.  You would need $A$, $B$, and $C$ to be invertible first in order to find the formula.  So I am guessing the question first stated that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are invertible?

Comment: Your way of attempting to set text within mathematical notation is not correct usage.  I fixed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user46944 I think so. This is one of the exercises on inverse matrices in the book, so perhaps it's implied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say matrices $A$ and $B$ are equal, i.e., $A = B$, then since they are equal, if one is invertible, the other better be invertible too since they are the same matrix, and they better have the *same* inverse (by a uniqueness argument I detailed below).

So $AB = C$ implies $(AB)^{-1} = C^{-1}$, since $AB$ is the same matrix as $C$ (which is what the equality says).

Note that the fact you can invert both sides doesn't just depend on the fact that both sides represent the same matrix $A$ (which is invertible).  It also depends on the fact that if a matrix is invertible, its inverse is *unique*.  An easy proof of this is here:

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix.  Suppose $B$ and $C$ are both the inverses of $A$, i.e., $AB = BA = I$, and $AC = CA = I$.

Then $B = BI = B(AC) = (BA)C = IC = C$, so $B$ and $C$ are the same matrix.  (I used here that matrix multiplication is associative, i.e., $B(AC) = (BA)C$).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Especially the AB = C implies $$(AB)^{-1} = C^{-1}$$

Comment: @MichaelBarton I'm glad to hear it. :)